# Reactjs with LinkedStateMixin and select with multiple options

Tags: reactjs

Using Reactjs, I want to have a single handleChange method handling the modifications of all my form elements.

I understand that the [LinkedStateMixin](http://facebook.github.io/react/docs/two-way-binding-helpers.html) exists for this reason, and that I should use

```
render: function() {
    return <select multiple={{ true }} valueLink={this.linkState('value')}>...options...</select>;
  }
```

to bind the status of my select element.

But it seems that this way of doing things does not work with multiple selects : the state.value is updated but with only one value (when I select 2 options, I can see React update the DOM and it systematically removes one of the selection).

So my question is : is LinkedStateMixin a dead-end for this use case ? How do you handle this select-multiple use case ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The root problem is that `.value` for select elements with the `multiple` attribute only returns the value of the first selected option element it contains. So, when the ValueLink mixin calls `event.target.value` to get the `select`'s new value, it doesn't return the required array to make the `value` property work.

You could build a little wrapper around `select` to make this work; here's my version ([plus a JSFiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/BinaryMuse/wQ4MP/)):

```javascript
// A select element that supports `multiple` and `valueLink` correctly
var BetterSelect = React.createClass({
  render: function() {
    if (this.props.valueLink) {
      return this.transferPropsTo(
        <select value={this.props.valueLink.value}
                valueLink={null} onChange={this.handleChange}>
          {this.props.children}
        </select>
      );
    } else {
      return this.transferPropsTo(
        <select onChange={this.handleChange}>
          {this.props.children}
        </select>
      );
    }
  },

  handleChange: function(e) {
    var selectedValue;
    if (this.props.multiple) {
      // We have to iterate the `options` elements
      // to figure out which ones are selected.
      selectedValue = [];
      var options = e.target.options;
      for (var i = 0, l = options.length; i < l; i++) {
        if (options[i].selected) {
          selectedValue.push(options[i].value);
        }
      }
    } else {
      selectedValue = e.target.value;
    }

    // Fire onChange manually if it exists since we overwrote it
    this.props.onChange && this.props.onChange(e);

    // Finally, manually take care of any valueLink passed
    if (this.props.valueLink) {
      this.props.valueLink.requestChange(selectedValue);
    }
  }
});


// Let's try it out:
var Application = React.createClass({
  mixins: [React.addons.LinkedStateMixin],

  getInitialState: function() {
    return { value: ['Apples', 'Oranges'] };
  },

  render: function() {
    return (
      <div>
        <pre>{JSON.stringify(this.state.value)}</pre>
        <BetterSelect multiple valueLink={this.linkState('value')}>
          <option value='Apples'>Apples</option>
          <option value='Bananas'>Bananas</option>
          <option value='Oranges'>Oranges</option>
        </BetterSelect>
      </div>
    );
  }
});
```

Comment: I don't understand why the select "value" property accepts an array as a setter when multiple=true ; but only returns the first value when used as a getter ; this feels weird.

Comment: You're setting the value on the react component, but from a DOM event `event.target` is the actual DOM node.

Comment: I've opened an issue to make this work with `ReactLink`, btw: https://github.com/facebook/react/pull/1761

Comment: OK thanks ; I thought Reactjs had mapped value to selectedIndex but I just realized that value is a valid attribute on HTMLSelectElement https://developer.mozilla.org/fr/docs/Web/API/HTMLSelectElement ; too bad Reactjs doesn't hide this complexity in their mixin